# how to pass values in method calling in c#

Tags: c#, checkbox, event-handling, radio-button

I came across this situation: "If I choose a radio button and a specific checkbox is checked then the text of the radio button should be copied into a textbox".

```
public void radiobutton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    object s;
    s = radiobutton.Text;
    checkBox2_CheckedChanged(s,e);
}

private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
    {
        textBox.Text = Convert.ToString(sender);
    }
}
```

I tried this code, but it's not working. What could be causing it to not function properly?

Comment: as the method has been called in the radio button change event then it will load the text to the check box text , but when checkbox is selected again the event will call the CheckedChanged method and there is no data in the sender object at that time...

Comment: otherwise you can do that you check the checkbox check validation in the same radiochecked event and do copy the text

Comment: "not working" is not a valid bug description. Tell us, what happened and what you expected to happen. Also, have you tried debugging?

Comment: Something simple, but you can just do a `if(checkBox2.Checked)` instead of `if(checkBox2.Checked==true)`. Since the `Checked` property of a `checkbox` control is just a `bool` anyway.

Answer (score 8):

well you can do it in a much easier way :

```
public void radiobutton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked == true) 
    {
        textBox1.Text = radiobutton.Text;
    } 
}
```

Comment: easier, but it does not satisfy all cases. What about if checkbox is clicked after radiobutton ?

Comment: well that's true , in that case you need another event handler , but the question says **If I choose a radio button and chosen a specific check box** which means choosing the `checkbox` has happened before `radiobutton` I think

Comment: I read it that way as well, Mehran. Sounds like the user wants to perform that copy of text only when the checkbox is checked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, remember it is a object at this point.

```
   private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
        {
            textBox.Text = (((object[])(sender))[0]).ToString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

Why not just this? Is there a specific reason that you are calling the `checkBox2_CheckedChanged` event inside the `radiobutton_CheckedChanged` event?

```
public void radiobutton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked == true)
    {
        textBox.Text = radiobutton.Text;
    }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Else for the sake of code management. You can do this and just pass on the `radiobutton_CheckedChanged` event to the `checkBox2_CheckedChanged` event.

```
public void radiobutton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox2_CheckedChanged(s,e);
}
```

Where the `checkBox2_CheckedChanged` event is as follows.

```
private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked)
    {
        textBox.Text = radiobutton.Text;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear, but this is my understanding :

When a checkbox is selected, you want the text of the selected radiobutton in a textbox. You can click first in radiobutton then checkbox, or checkbox then changing radiobutton.

You have to trigger each event, and have one action (updating textbox) :

```
    private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdateTextBox();

        // other thing if you want
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdateTextBox();

        // other thing if you want
    }

    private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdateTextBox();

        // other thing if you want
    }

    private void UpdateTextBox()
    {
        if (this.checkBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            String value = String.Empty;
            if (this.radioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                value = this.radioButton1.Text;
            }
            else if (this.radioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                value = this.radioButton2.Text;
            }
            // and so ....

            this.textBox1.Text = value;
        }
        else
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
        }
    }
```